# Kendo UI Autocomplete custom binding

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I have service which give me top 10 records of result which is typed by user in search TextBox. So on keypress of textbox there is call of my service. Here i am using KendoUI AutoComplete so the problem is my service get call before autocomplete define. Can any one have idea?

```
<input data-bind="value: searchString, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"  placeholder="Search me.."/>
searchString: ko.computed({
        read: function () { },
        write: function (val) {            
           BindAutoTextBox(val);
            return false;
        }
    }).extend({ throttle: 1000 }),

function BindAutoTextBox(val){

 ServiceHelper.getData('search/users?SearchText='+val, function (data) {     

        $("#LeftSearch").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: {
                data: data
            },
            dataTextField: "User_Code",
            template: '<table width="100%"><tr><td width="20%" valign="top">#:User_Code#</td><td width="30%" valign="top">#:Full_Name#</td><td width="30%" 

valign="top">#:Group_Name#</td></tr></table>'

        });

        var autoComplete = $("#LeftSearch").data("kendoAutoComplete");
        // set width of the drop-down list
        autoComplete.list.width(355);

    }, null, 'http://abc/ApplicationRestService/', 'Users');

}
```

Can any one give me solution in brief detail code ?

Comment: Can you share the code with me as I have bit kendo experience

Comment: Please try with the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560736/kendo-ui-autocomplete-datasource-transport-reads-only-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution using setDataSource of Autocomplete kendoUI you can change your datasource from your service which will getting call on keypress...

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
});
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [ "Bananas", "Cherries" ]
});
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autocomplete.setDataSource(dataSource);
</script>



 $("#autocomplete").keyup(function (e) {

    var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
     dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: ["Apples", "Oranges","Bananas", "Cherries"]
                    });
     autocomplete.setDataSource(dataSource);                

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this from my ipad so I can't give any sample code at the moment, but you seem to be doing things backwards. You are asking your server for data yourself, then creating a kendo autocomplete with the result. Also, the autocomplete will be created each time you enter text in the box. The proper way to use kendo is to create the autocomplete when your page loads and set up its datasource to query your server. You shouldn't need your knockout code or your getData function at all. The autocomplete widget will fetch data using its datasource when characters are typed into the input box on its own.
Look at the examples on http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html